# Using HighCharts with LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, highcharts

I would like to use Highchart for laravel but i don't know how to pass data from controller to blade with the correct syntax. Actually i'm using static data and the graph is displayed correctly.

**statistiche.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="container2" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
// Create the chart
        Highcharts.stockChart('container2', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Richieste scadute',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 4), 0.28],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.25],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 27), 0.2],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 2), 0.28]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Richieste evase',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 29), 0],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.4],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 1), 0.25],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 1), 1.66],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 10), 1.8]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Richieste in attesa',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 25), 0],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 6), 0.25],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 20), 1.41],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.64],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 4), 1.6]
                ]
            }]
        });
```

I would to use controller for extract data and pass there into the blade.
Some advice?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to pass data to a highcharts graph.

1) Use `$.getJSON` to get data and fill in the series.

```
$.getJSON("{{ route('get-json-route') }}", function(chart){
    var hashObj = {};
    var seriesObj = {};

    var graphs = {'dd':'graph dd', 'ld' : 'graph ld title'};

    for(var nam in graphs) {
        seriesObj['visible'] = 1;
        seriesObj['color'] = '#00CC00';
        seriesObj['name'] = chart[nam]['name'] + ' stats';
        seriesObj['data'] = chart[nam]['data'];
        highcharts.addSeries(seriesObj);
    }
    highcharts.redraw();
});
```

2) Pass data directly into your blade template using `json_encode`:

```
seriesObj['data'] = {!! json_encode($data) !!};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Dude use special library:
https://github.com/julles/laravel-highcharts

Just install and work:

```
composer require muhamadrezaar/highcharts
```